# Show an app on Slingshot

Tags: slingshot

I was instructed that by adding the line `OnlyShowin=Pantheon` in the `.desktop` file of an app, would make it show on Slingshot menus. I did that with gufw (the firewall app), but it didn't happen. Please advise on what I'm missing. The `.desktop` file (located in `/usr/share/applications`) is as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Version=1.0 
Name=Firewall Configuration 
Comment=An easy way to configure your firewall
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;Security;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-SystemSett‌​ings;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;X-XFCE-SettingsDialog;X-XFCE-SystemSettings;System 
Exec=gufw 
Icon=gufw 
Terminal=false 
Type=Application 
X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=gufw 
X-Unity-Settings-Panel=gufw 
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gufw
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the .desktop file so we can check and see what might be missing? Thanks!

Comment: This is the content:

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firewall Configuration
Comment=An easy way to configure your firewall
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;Security;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;X-XFCE-SettingsDialog;X-XFCE-SystemSettings;System
Exec=gufw
Icon=gufw
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=gufw
X-Unity-Settings-Panel=gufw
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gufw

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format above comment to show appropriately.

Comment: No worries! I probably should've asked this before, but where is the .desktop file located?

Comment: /usr/share/applications

Answer (score 1):

Remove `OnlyShowin=Pantheon` from the `.desktop` file. I didn't have to add `OnlyShowin=Pantheon` to get my `.desktop` file to show in Slingshot.

Comment: I added OnlyShowin=... because the app didn't show in Slingshot.

Comment: Does It work without  `OnlyShowin=...`

Comment: Right now the desktop file doesn't have OnlyShowin=... and still it doesn't work.

Comment: Remove ```X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=gufw 
X-Unity-Settings-Panel=gufw 
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gufw``` from the ```.desktop``` file

Comment: Sorry. Your suggestion didn't solve my problem. Gufw still doesn't show on Slingshot menus.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` instead of `/usr/share/applications`, does that fix the problem?

From the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines#app-launchers):

> Users may create their own launchers by putting .desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: Sorry. Doing your recommendation doesn't solve the problem. I am studying Mario's solution, but it seems a little complicated, an arises questions. I will comment on them shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is to show an application or program in the Slingshot menu, I have done it by following the instructions located [here](http://elementaryosandmore.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-add-and-modify-applications-in.html).

Which in short are:

`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends alacarte`

Then

`sudo scratch-text-editor /usr/share/alacarte/Alacarte/MenuEditor.py`

There you have to replace the string `applications.menu` with `pantheon-applications.menu` (all occurrences).

Finally, from the terminal: `sudo alacarte`

And there, you're done.  You can now add shortcuts to the Slingshot menu and personalize categories.

Comment: Mario, thanks for your suggestion, and I'm considering it. But, still I would like to understand the problem in this particular app (gufw). Before this one, I have installed like five or six different apps from the Software Center and in none of them I had to do anything for them to show on Slingshot in their corresponding category. I tried to identify if there was a distinctive characteristic on the desktop file by comparing it with the others, but I couldn't find any. Your additional thoughts will be appreciated. Tks.